# Why does SignInManager fetch the user twice on login?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

When supplying a username to `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()` it first calls `FindByNameAsync()` but then it calls `FindByIdAsync()`. I implemented a custom UserStore, but I don't understand why it calls both, making two database calls? It seems like unnecessary overhead.

In both cases I'm returning the same IUser object with a different Where criteria. Is that what I'm supposed to do?

```
public Task<MyAppIdentityUser> FindByIdAsync(long userId)
{
    Task<MyAppIdentityUser> task = _db.Profile.Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
        .Select(x => new MyAppIdentityUser { Id = x.UserId, UserName = x.UserName })
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    return task;
}

public Task<MyAppIdentityUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
{
    Task<MyAppIdentityUser> task =  _db.Profile.Where(x => x.UserName == userName)
        .Select(x => new MyAppIdentityUser { Id = x.UserId, UserName = x.UserName })
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    return task;
}
```

Additional - I also noticed there's a 3rd and 4th query for GetPasswordHashAsync() and GetLockoutEnabledAsync(). Why are all of these calls necessary and can't be bundled together in a single call?

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured it out after some head scratching. When calling `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()` with a string username and password, it first queries the DB to get the IUser object with its Id key from the DB ([source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/3277f6876827851be07e98b33bffd836418489c4/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/SignInManager.cs#L286)). However it then calls itself again with the IUser object but does several checks which call `GetUserIdAsync()` over and over again, despite the manager already having it. Don't know why it does this out of the box.